# Enterprise Manager Errors on Oracle 10g2 on Linux

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-enterprise-manager

I have installed an instance of Oracle Enterprise Manager Database Control 10g Release 10.2.0.1.0 in Centos 6.5
Attempts to launch the Enterprise Manager agent with the command:

`emctl start dbconsole`

After a few minutes, I said that failure.
Logs throw me:

**emagent.log**

> 07/01/2016 11:16:22 Thread-3086911712 Agent 10.1.0.4.1 Starting from
>   /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0 (00701) 07/01/2016 11:16:22
>   Thread-3086911712 EMAgent started successfully (00702)

**emagent.trc**

> 07/01/2016 11:16:22 Thread-3086911712 WARN http: snmehl_connect:
>   failed to connect (myserver: 3600): Connection refused (error = 111)
>   Thread-3086911712 07.01.2016 11:16:22 pingManager ERROR:
>   nmepm_pingReposURL: Can not connect to http: // myserver: 3600 / em /
>   upload /: retStatus = -32 07/01/2016 11:16:22 WARN command
>   Thread-3086911712: Subsystem Job Timeout Set at 600 seconds 07/01/2016
>   11:16:22 Thread-3086911712 WARN upload: Upload manager has not Failure
>   script: disabled 07/01/2016 11:16:22 Thread-3086911712 WARN upload:
>   Recovering left over xml files in upload directory 07/01/2016 11:16:22
>   Thread-3086911712 WARN upload: Recovered 109 left over xml files in
>   upload directory 07/01/2016 11:16:22 Thread-WARN 125 881 248 http:
>   snmehl_connect: failed to connect (myserver: 3600): Connection refused
>   (error = 111)
>   07.01.2016 11:16:22 125 881 248 Thread-ERROR command: nmejcn: http connection failed to http: // myserver: 3600 / em / upload /:
>   retStatus = -32 07/01/2016 11:16:22 Thread-3086911712 WARN metadata:
>   Metric Disk_Path does not Have any data columns 07/01/2016 11:16:22
>   Thread-3086911712 WARN metadata: Metric osm_diskGroupPolicies does not
>   Have any data columns
>   07.01.2016 11:16:22 132 508 576 Thread-upload ERROR: Error in uploadXMLFiles. Trying again in 60.00 seconds. 07/01/2016 11:16:22
>   Thread-27175840 WARN http: snmehl_connect: failed to connect
>   (myserver: 3600): Connection refused (error = 111) 07/01/2016 11:16:22
>   Thread-pingManager 27,175,840 ERROR: nmepm_pingReposURL: Can not
>   connect to http: // myserver: 3600 / em / upload /: retStatus = -32

**emdctl.trc**

> 07/01/2016 11:21:53 Thread-3086911712 WARN http: snmehl_connect:
>   failed to connect (myserver: 3873): Connection refused (error = 111)

Answer (score 0):

I could already solve, I did the following:

1. set ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME
2. emca -repos recreate
3. emca -config dbcontrol db
4. emctl start dbconsole